# Load raphael chart with jquery mobile page tranistion

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, raphael

I am trying to load a raphael chart on a page transition

The graph working it i add the div that hooks to the graph, but if i add it in one of the data-role="page" it does not work. I had a similar issue with leaflet maps and got a workaround with

```
 $("#dashboard").on("pageshow", function(event, ui) { 
    map.invalidateSize(false);
 });
```

Although the map was showing it was only showing in a small block in the corner. I have tried

```
<a href="#stats" data-transition="flow" data-enhance="false" data-ajax="false" title="">
```

But that does not work.

I have also tried ( not too sure my reasoning for this besides vain hope )

```
 $("#dashboard").on("pageshow", function(event, ui) { 
      $('#graph1").load();
 });
```

I cant show the whole code because of copyright but i have a div

```
<div class="graph" id="graph1"></div>
```

And then set the properties

```
 $(function() {
             $('#graph1').isochart({
                points                  : [20, 28, 43, 32, 87, 38, 23, 56, 54, 35, 36, 45, 31, 86, 54, 32, 46],
                bodyColorStart          : '#9d0000',
                bodyColorEnd            : '#c61f1f',
                capsColorStart          : '#9d0000',
                capsColorEnd            : '#c61f1f',
                stroke                  : '#c61f1f',
                shadowSize              : 40,
                shadowOpacity           : 0.5,
                showPointsDataParent    : "page"
            });
        });
```

I dont think there is anything wrong with the code to create the graph because, like i said it works on the first page. I think this is more to do with the way that jquery mobile uses ajax in its pages.

Comment: Can you at least put together a jsFiddle that demonstrates the problem without including copyrighted material?  Here is one I put together that transitions and draws a gRaphael chart: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8UuYv/ maybe you can edit it to create your problem...

Comment: Hey, thanks for effort. I really appreciate it. I have been having quite a serious problem with JQM no fitting properly on the ipad ( there is a 200px space at the bottom that should not be there). I thought it was just minor but i am not sure whats going on, and instead of fighting  i am just writing very simple page transitions and then just css'ng it up. This avoids all the map , graph and any other library conflicts that might occur. Cheers